# Replacing characters in a string when between double quotes

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to replace commas in my strings, between dynamic positions (ie. between double quotes). Note that I will not have more than 2 occurrences of double quotes in my strings if that matters.

My example:

```
'randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN, GUY, DANIEL",sun'
```

Desired output:

```
'randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN GUY DANIEL",sun'
```

So far I've tried things with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` mixed with `INSTR()` but could not get anything done.

Cheers

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz No it's not. I am editing the example so it's clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short & clean.**

```
with t(str) as (select 'randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN, GUY, DANIEL",sun' from dual)
select regexp_replace(str,'(^[^"]*|[^"]*$)|,','\1') as result
from   t
```

-

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                     RESULT                     |
+------------------------------------------------+
| randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN GUY DANIEL",sun |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f9aa/48/0)

In addition -
**Short and clean generic version**

```
with t(str) as 
(
             select 'Well,you,went,uptown,riding,in,your,limousine' from dual
  union all  select 'With,your,fine,"Park, Avenue, clothes"' from dual
  union all  select 'You,had,the,"Dom, Perignon",in,your,hand,"And, the, spoon",up,your,nose' from dual
  union all  select '"And, when, you",wake,"up, in, the, morning"' from dual
  union all  select '"With, your, head, on, fire"' from dual
  union all  select '"And",your,"eyes, too, bloody","to, see",Go,"on, and, cry, in",your,coffee,"But","don''t","come, bitchin''","to, me"' from dual

)
select regexp_replace(str, '((^|").*?("|$))|,', '\1') as result
from   t
```

--

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   RESULT                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Well,you,went,uptown,riding,in,your,limousine                                                              |
| With,your,fine,"Park Avenue clothes"                                                                       |
| You,had,the,"Dom Perignon",in,your,hand,"And the spoon",up,your,nose                                       |
| "And when you",wake,"up in the morning"                                                                    |
| "With your head on fire"                                                                                   |
| "And",your,"eyes too bloody","to see",Go,"on and cry in",your,coffee,"But","don't","come bitchin'","to me" |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f9aa/47/0)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are working on CSV, then it is possible that you will also have nested double quotes as per this sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN, GUY, DANIEL",sun' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'randomtext,123,"A, ""BC"", D",sun' FROM DUAL;
```

You can use the regular expression `^(.*?)("([^\"]|\\")+")(.*)$` to match the terms before, inside the quotes and after and then replace commas in only the middle parts:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+")(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
       || REPLACE(
            REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+")(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ),
            ','
          )
       || REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+")(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 4 ) replaced_value
FROM   test_data
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> VALUE                                            | REPLACED_VALUE                                
> :----------------------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------------
> randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN, GUY, DANIEL",sun | randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN GUY DANIEL",sun
> randomtext,123,"A, ""BC"", D",sun                | randomtext,123,"A ""BC"" D",sun
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=566544a5b6e963e1a7a1b8f377374ebb)*

---

## Update

If you need to handle multiple quoted terms in a string (with nested quotes):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN, GUY, DANIEL",sun' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'randomtext,123,"A, ""BC"", D",sun' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E,"F, G",H,"I, ""J""", K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'L,M,N' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH replacements( value, prefix, suffix ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+"|$)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         || REPLACE(
              REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+"|$)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ),
              ','
            ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+"|$)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 4 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         prefix
         || REGEXP_SUBSTR( suffix, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+"|$)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         || REPLACE(
              REGEXP_SUBSTR( suffix, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+"|$)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ),
              ','
            ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( suffix, '^(.*?)("([^\"]|"")+"|$)(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 4 )
  FROM   replacements
  WHERE  suffix IS NOT NULL
         
)
SELECT value,
       prefix AS replaced_value
FROM   replacements
WHERE  suffix IS NULL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> VALUE                                            | REPLACED_VALUE                                
> :----------------------------------------------- | :---------------------------------------------
> L,M,N                                            | L,M,N                                         
> randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN, GUY, DANIEL",sun | randomtext,123,"JEAN SEBASTIEN GUY DANIEL",sun
> randomtext,123,"A, ""BC"", D",sun                | randomtext,123,"A ""BC"" D",sun               
> E,"F, G",H,"I, ""J""", K                         | E,"F G",H,"I ""J""", K
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=029b4d3aa068ce79cf9b0620fa2989c4)*

Comment: Thank you for your time, just felt like the other answer was (sort of) cleaner. Just personal preferences but that's much appreciated anyway :)

Comment: @MonsieurTruite - please note that recursive queries have a significant performance cost. Any additional regexp function also adds to the performance cost.